# Lightning datatable in lwc to show multiple urls in single cell

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, url

Is it possible to add multiple links to a single Lightning Datatable cell. For example, as in the screenshot.

it should be something like this[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post relevant code - see [ask]

Comment: I've closed this question because it is a copy and paste of another user's question with no additional information added. I'd be happy to reopen the question if it is edited to contain code.